# Forking Polygon PoS with hardhat + Alchemy Failing with Connection Timeout Error

Tags: hardhat, polygon, alchemy

I am trying to fork the Polygon PoS with Alchemy and it gives me the error of timeout while my internet connection is pretty good. I don't know why sometimes it runs successfully and sometimes it fails.
Following is the error I am getting while trying to do the fork.
I have followed this: https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/docs/guides/forking-other-networks

[image]

Comment: Please, do not post text as image.